# graphqlKoa is not a function

Tags: javascript, graphql, koa

I am starting to learn Javascript from a C# background and have started building a simple GraphQL API as my first project but I am struggling to get example code working and I am not sure where to look for the solution.

I am following the usage section here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-koa

But the following line is throwing an error:

```
router.post('/graphql', graphqlKoa({ schema: ironManSchema }));
```

> TypeError: graphqlKoa is not a function

I am not sure what is causing this, is it a bug in the example code? A problem with trying to use ES6? Something caused by the version of Node.JS I have installed? (Upgraded to 10.1.0 just in case) Or perhaps it is because I am trying to debug it in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It sounds like you're not importing the library correctly. It should be either `import { graphqlKoa } from 'apollo-server-koa'` or `const { graphqlKoa } = require('apollo-server-koa')`

Comment: I am importing the library like this: const graphqlKoa = require('apollo-server-koa'); are curly braces required? They don't seem to be needed for my other importing lines to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apollo-server-koa` module does not export a function -- if it did then you *would* be able to simply import it like this:

```
const graphqlKoa = require('apollo-server-koa')
```

Instead, it effectively exports an object, with one of it's properties being graphqlKoa, which *is* a function. That means to use it in your project, you should do one of the following:

```
const apolloServer = require('apollo-server-koa')
const graphqlKoa = apolloServer.graphqlKoa

const graphqlKoa = require('apollo-server-koa').graphqlKoa

const { graphqlKoa } = require('apollo-server-koa')

// ES6 syntax
import { graphqlKoa } from 'apollo-server-koa'
```

The curly brackets in the third example are just [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 4):

`apollo-server-koa` has no `graphqlKoa` anymore since 2.x. You should use 1.x version.